# SharePoint Framework with React TypeScript react-router-dom error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I am using SPFX with React TypeScript for developing on SP.

In order to apply routing between components, I am using react-router-dom. However, I am facing this issue:

```
Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\react-router\index.d.ts(163,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\react-router\index.d.ts(163,70): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

It appears that it is a problem with TS version which I cannot change as it is restricted with SPFX and I believe I am using the suitable version for `react-router-dom`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.3",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "15.6.6"
  },
```

SPFX: 1.4.1
TypeScript: 2.4.2

What would be the best way to setup routing with SPFX and note that I am using SP2019 On-Premise with Workbench.